# How do you retrieve the hours of the daily min and max of time series data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have an hourly price of an asset EVMOS in a pandas df.

```
                       EVMOS    date        time
datetime            
2022-08-25 21:00:00 2.830231    2022-08-25  21:00:00
2022-08-25 22:00:00 2.762030    2022-08-25  22:00:00
2022-08-25 23:00:00 2.714075    2022-08-25  23:00:00
2022-08-26 00:00:00 2.650786    2022-08-26  00:00:00
2022-08-26 01:00:00 2.653450    2022-08-26  01:00:00 
...
...
```

I would like to know to what the daily max values correspond. I have calculated the max and min values with:

```
price.groupby('date')['EVMOS'].max()
```

I have the results here:

```
date
2022-08-25    2.830231
2022-08-26    2.802465
2022-08-27    2.443283
2022-08-28    2.423311
2022-08-29    2.607691
...
...
```

I would like to know at what time each day these max prices happened.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the idxmax function in Pandas.

> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.

Src:https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2022-08-25 21:00:00', 2.830231, '2022-08-25', '21:00:00'],
    ['2022-08-25 22:00:00', 2.762030, '2022-08-25', '22:00:00'],
    ['2022-08-25 23:00:00', 2.714075, '2022-08-25', '23:00:00'],
    ['2022-08-26 00:00:00', 2.650786, '2022-08-26', '00:00:00'],
    ['2022-08-26 01:00:00', 2.653450, '2022-08-26', '01:00:00'] 
], columns=['datetime', 'EVMOS', 'date', 'time'])

max_indexes = df.groupby('date')['EVMOS'].idxmax()
df.loc[max_indexes]
```

If you only want a Series of the times, you could change the last line to this:

```
df.loc[max_indexes, ['time']].reset_index(drop=1)
```